# testng test via selenium grid returning error for ie driver path but test is for firefox

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, grid, testng

I am trying to run a test using testng via selenium grid.

these tests worked previously, but today, i am getting this error:

```
The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property
```

That error does not make sense because my test is supposed to be running on firefox.

Here's the bits....

**TESTNG**

```
 <test name="Run using Firefox 25 on Windows 7">
  <parameter name="GridBrowser"  value="firefox25win7"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.coursestrand_courseoverviewpanel.CourseOverviewPanelTest"/>
    </classes>
 </test>
```

**CODE SNIPPET FOR ABOVE VALUE**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

     public class Configuration {

        public static DesiredCapabilities setCap; 
        public static final String GRID_HUB_URL = "http://192.168.53.67:4444/wd/hub";

        public static String SeleniumGridSetup(String gridBrowser) {

        String newGridBrowser = gridBrowser;

        switch (newGridBrowser) {


        case "firefox25win7": 
            System.out.println("Firefox Version 25.0 on Windows 7");
            setCap= DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            setCap.setBrowserName("firefox25win7"); 
            setCap.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);
            break;
        }

    return newGridBrowser;
}
```

**HERE'S MY TEST**

```
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import com.environments.Configuration;
import com.thoughtworks.twist.core.execution.TwistScenarioDataStore;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;

import org.testng.Assert;

   public class CourseOverviewPanelTest {

    public WebDriver browser;
    public static String url; 

    @Autowired
    private TwistScenarioDataStore scenarioStore;

    @Parameters({"GridBrowser"})
    public CourseOverviewPanelTest(String GridBrowser) throws Exception {           

    Configuration.SeleniumGridSetup(GridBrowser);
    browser = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Configuration.GRID_HUB_URL), Configuration.setCap);

    url = Configuration.getUrl();
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.navigate().to(url + "/course-list.html");
}

public CourseOverviewPanelTest() throws Exception {

    browser = new FirefoxDriver(); 
    browser.manage().window().maximize();

    url = Configuration.getUrl();
    browser.navigate().to(url + "/course-list.html");

}

// Test methods start from here for Landing page carousel

@Test
public void displayCourseTitleAndDescription() throws Exception {

    final String courseTitle = browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/section/article/ul/li[1]/h4")).getText();
    Assert.assertEquals("Maths", courseTitle);
}
```

**SELENIUM GRID NODE**

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role webdriver -hub  http://192.168.53.67:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="firefox25win7",platform=WINDOWS -port 5585
```

**THIS IS THE CONFIG CREATED IN GRID WHEN FIREFOX NODE IS RUN**

```
role:webdriver

remoteHost:http://192.168.53.70:5585

hubHost:192.168.53.67

hubPort:4444

prioritizer:null

timeout:300000

throwOnCapabilityNotPresent:true

nodePolling:5000

url:http://192.168.53.70:5585

newSessionWaitTimeout:-1

proxy:org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy

cleanUpCycle:5000

hub:http://192.168.53.67:4444/grid/register

port:5585

browser:browserName=firefox25win7,platform=WINDOWS

browserTimeout:0

host:192.168.53.70

servlets:[]

maxSession:5

registerCycle:5000

capabilityMatcher:org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher

register:true
```

When I execute the testng test, the error is returning in the console.

**Note:** 
If I do set the path to the executable driver (in the node), then the test runs in IE!

**FURTHER NOTE:**
The issue also occurs when I run my chrome node, which looks like this:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/selenium-server/chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.53.67:4444/grid/register -port 5566 -browser browserName="chromeLatestWindows7",platform=WINDOWS
```

The crazy thing is if i change -Dwebdriver.**chrome**.driver=C:/selenium-server/chromedriver.exe in the above node to 
-Dwebdriver.**ie**.driver=C:/selenium-server/chromedriver.exe then my test runs fine in chrome!!

Comment: can you add more code to your snippet, what is the rest of the code and where is it being called?

Comment: added most of my code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the browsername.  As per [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2#Optional_parameters) the allowed values are "Parameters allowed for -browser: browserName={android, chrome, firefox, htmlunit, internet explorer, iphone, opera}".  Change the name of firefox25win7 to firefox and it should work.